# Load jquery only related to the particular popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui-dialog

Buttons for call popups:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" data-for="cleaning-info" class="actionButton dialog-link">
            Cleaning</button>
     <button type="button" data-for="notes-info" class="actionButton dialog-link">
            Notes</button>
 </div>
```

Jquery UI popup 1 :

```
<div class="pet-profile dialog" id="cleaning-info" data-width="600" data-title="Pet Sitter Cleaning">
        <%  using (Html.BeginAbsoluteRouteForm("PetDetail", new { controller = "PetSitters", action = "SavePetSitterCleaningRecords", ownerKey = Model.Owner.Key, petKey = Model.Key }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addPetSitterCleaning" }))
            { %>

          <%: Html.CompleteEditorFor(m => m.PetSitterCleaningRecord.WhereIsTheScoop)%>
           <button type="submit" class="actionButton default">
                    Save</button>

        <%} %>
    </div>
```

Jquery UI popup 2 :

```
<div class="pet-profile dialog" id="notes-info" data-width="550" data-title="Pet Sitter Notes">
    <%  using (Html.BeginAbsoluteRouteForm("PetDetail", new { controller = "PetSitters", action = "SavePetSitterNotes", ownerKey = Model.Owner.Key, petKey = Model.Key }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addPetSitterNotes" }))
        { %>

        <%: Html.CompleteEditorFor(m => m.PetSitterNote.Note1)%>
        <button type="submit" class="actionButton default">
                Save</button>

    <%} %>
</div>
```

Jquery code for popup 1 & 2 :

```
//popup 1
var dialogPetSitterCleaningInfo = $('#cleaning-info');

//save button
var petSitterCleaningSave = dialogPetSitterCleaningInfo.find($('.actionButton.default[type=submit]'));
var petSitterCleaningForm = dialogPetSitterCleaningInfo.find($("#addPetSitterCleaning"));

 //disable 
  petSitterCleaningForm.submit(function () {
  petSitterCleaningSave.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  petSitterCleaningSave.addClass('disabled');
 });

//popup 2
var dialogPetSitterNotesInfo = $('#notes-info');

 //save button
 var petSitterNotesSave = dialogPetSitterNotesInfo.find($('.actionButton.default[type=submit]'));
 var petSitterNotesForm = dialogPetSitterNotesInfo.find($("#addPetSitterNotes"));

 //disable 
 petSitterNotesForm.submit(function () {
 petSitterNotesSave.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 petSitterNotesSave.addClass('disabled');
 });
```

Above all codes are in same file `CustomersHomeModal.aspx`

UI is as below:

[image]

**My Question:**

How can I call only the related popup jquery code when press the relevant popup's button.
Currently first run itself load all the jquery code (related to both popups).I need to avoid that.

How to do that (simple example is highly appreciate)?

Comment: Do you mean "how to put the code snippets inside two different js functions"?

Comment: @gaurav Nope.I need to load the relevant jq when press a popup button. Currently when load above page it loads all jq at once.I need to avoid that.

Comment: Then I think you should return some javascript result from your action and this action should be called via ajax and the result script should be simply eval(ed).

Comment: @gaurav this thing is client side.So I need to handle it within client.Can I do that ?

Comment: Yes but that would be a bad approach.. I mean the time taken to load the script on click of the button will annoy the user. Basically you can put this js in a js file and load that js file on click of the button.